Using Spring OAuth2 Client but not for authentication
I want to connect multiple social accounts to one user profile without a social login. How can I do this with Spring?
I thought I could use Spring's OAuth2 Login to do the Authorization Code Flow to get the access token but I don't want to secure my application with a social login. I only need the access/refresh tokens to access user resources in the future. How to do this with Spring? Is there any other way to do this?
Using this configuration I'm able to do the Authorization Code Flow. But I only want this flow to trigger when I go to a specific endpoint. However, I don't want Spring to protect my endpoints with it/letting users login using it, for which I have a separate system.
private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone", "https://mail.google.com")
            .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?prompt=consent&access_type=offline")
            .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
            .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
            .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
            .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
            .clientName("Google")
            .build();
}

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login.defaultSuccessUrl("/test/authorized/google"));

Relevant dependencies:
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

I have seen How to use Spring Security OAuth 2 client without using it for login/authentication purposes but I am using Spring Boot instead of XML configuration and I don't know how the answer to that question would apply to me.
